# Haskell Fractional could not deduce (RealFrac a) arising from a use of `round'

Tags: haskell

I do not want to perform integer divison. I want to take in a fractional input type, do a division with it, round the result to an integer and return that.

```
piCalc :: (Fractional a, Ord a, Integral b) => a -> (a, b)
piCalc z = (piCalc' steps 1 0, steps)
    where steps = round $ (4-z)/(2*z) + 1

piCalc' :: (Integral a, Ord a, Fractional b) => a -> a -> a -> b
piCalc' 0 s k = 0
piCalc' steps s k = (fromInteger s*4)/(fromInteger 2*k + 1) + piCalc' (steps-1) ((-1)*s) (k+1)

main = do
    print (piCalc 0.001)
```

I get the following error:

```
Recursion.hs:59:19: error:
    * Could not deduce (RealFrac a) arising from a use of `round'
      from the context: (Fractional a, Ord a, Integral b)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   piCalc :: forall a b.
                             (Fractional a, Ord a, Integral b) =>
                             a -> (a, b)
        at Recursion.hs:57:1-58
      Possible fix:
        add (RealFrac a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            piCalc :: forall a b.
                      (Fractional a, Ord a, Integral b) =>
                      a -> (a, b)
    * In the first argument of `($)', namely `round'
      In the expression: round $ (4 - z) / (2 * z) + 1
      In an equation for `steps': steps = round $ (4 - z) / (2 * z) + 1
   |
59 |     where steps = round $ (4-z)/(2*z) + 1
   |                   ^^^^^

Recursion.hs:63:34: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Integer' with actual type `a'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          piCalc' :: forall a b.
                     (Integral a, Ord a, Fractional b) =>
                     a -> a -> a -> b
        at Recursion.hs:61:1-64
    * In the first argument of `fromInteger', namely `s'
      In the first argument of `(*)', namely `fromInteger s'
      In the first argument of `(/)', namely `(fromInteger s * 4)'
    * Relevant bindings include
        k :: a (bound at Recursion.hs:63:17)
        s :: a (bound at Recursion.hs:63:15)
        steps :: a (bound at Recursion.hs:63:9)
        piCalc' :: a -> a -> a -> b (bound at Recursion.hs:62:1)
   |
63 | piCalc' steps s k = (fromInteger s*4)/(fromInteger 2*k + 1) + piCalc' (steps-1) ((-1)*s) (k+1)
   |                                  ^^^
```

Changing Fractional to RealFrac in piCalc (the top function) fixed the first error for me but I don't understand why or know if this is a "good" solution. I could barely find any usage examples of RealFrac when searching google. I do not know what is causing the second error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RealFrac` constraint implies both `Real` and `Fractional`. `Real` means that the numbers must be 1-dimensional (in contrast to, say, 2-dimensional complex numbers, or higher dimensional vectors). `round` requires `Real`, because it must map its input on the 1-dimensional set of integers. And `round` obviously requires `Fractional`, otherwise it doesn't make much sense to round. So, `round` requires a `RealFrac` as input. Changing `Fractional` to `RealFrac` is the right solution to the first error.

The second error is because you specify that your types are `Integral`, but then you apply the `fromInteger` function which expects a concrete `Integer`. You should change `fromInteger` to `fromIntegral`.

Then you will still get an error, because you write `fromInteger 2*k`, which means `(fromInteger 2) * k` in Haskell, but you probably meant `fromInteger (2 * k)` or `2 * fromInteger k`. And this should also be changed to `fromIntegral`.

This code compiles without errors:

```hs
piCalc :: (RealFrac a, Ord a, Integral b) => a -> (a, b)
piCalc z = (piCalc' steps 1 0, steps)
    where steps = round $ (4-z)/(2*z) + 1

piCalc' :: (Integral a, Ord a, Fractional b) => a -> a -> a -> b
piCalc' 0 s k = 0
piCalc' steps s k = (fromIntegral s*4)/(2 * fromIntegral k + 1) + piCalc' (steps-1) ((-1)*s) (k+1)

main = do
    print (piCalc 0.001)
```

If you're just interested in calculating pi then it might make more sense to choose more concrete types, for example `Double` or `Rational` instead of `RealFrac a => a` and `Int` or `Integer` instead of `Integral a => a`. You can keep the implementation the same and only change the signatures:

```hs
piCalc :: Double -> (Double, Int)
piCalc z = (piCalc' steps 1 0, steps)
    where steps = round $ (4-z)/(2*z) + 1

piCalc' :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Double
piCalc' 0 s k = 0
piCalc' steps s k = (fromIntegral s*4)/(2 * fromIntegral k + 1) + piCalc' (steps-1) ((-1)*s) (k+1)

main = do
    print (piCalc 0.001)
```